# Cannot cast Outlook object to ReportItem

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to enumerate the different mail items in an Outlook folder.

Some of the mail items are ReportItems ... I can tell this because their Class = 46.  However, when I try to cast the __ComObject to a ReportItem using ((Outlook.ReportItem)item) I get this exception:

```
    AutoResolvedWinner  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The operation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Dynamic.IDispatchComObject.GetMembers(IEnumerable`1 names)}    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

If it helps, the MessageClass property of the object is "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"

Help would be appreciated.